# Jquery form submit issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, form-submit

i have a form with simple few html controls.i want to save data to mysql in ajax jquery.but it do not sumbit it.here is what i have tried

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({

          beforeSubmit : function() { 

          var lookup          = true;

          var validate        = false;
          $.ajax({

             async: false,

             url: 'user.php?username='+$('#username').val(),

             success: function(data) { }

         })
 validate =  $("#myForm").validate({rules: { price: { number: true, }, size: { number: true, }} , errorClass: 'form_fields_error',  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}}).form() ;
if(lookup && validate ){

                return true;

            }

            else{

                return true;

            }

          },
       target: '#showdata',

          success: function() { }

        });

      });

    $("#myForm").submit(function()
  {

 alert('this is not fired');
//e.preventDefault();
var formData = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax(
{
    type:'post',
    url:'administration/save_users.php',
    data:formData,
    beforeSend:function()
    {
       // launchpreloader();
    },
    complete:function()
    {
       // stopPreloader();
    },
    success:function(result)
    {
         alert(result);
    }

});

});
```

the form submit is not fired...what i am missing? i have form action="#"....

Comment: The code is not in a fit state for the question to be reliably addressed. Tidy it up and you will probably start to find answers for yourself.

Comment: It's JavaScript, not PHP, please re-format the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, presumably you're using the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

```
validate =  $("#myForm").validate({rules: { price: { number: true, }, size: { number: true, }} , errorClass: 'form_fields_error',  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}}).form() ;
```

Your code is all a mess with multiple `ajax` calls and a superfluous `submit` handler.  The fact that it's formatted poorly doesn't help us to unravel and troubleshoot.

[As per the jQuery Validate documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions),

> **submitHandler**, Callback, Default: default (native) form submit
>  Callback for handling the actual submit when the form
>   is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default
>   submit. **The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it
>   validated.**

This means that you should place your `ajax` inside the `submitHandler` callback function of the plugin.

You...

- do not need to use a `submit` handler (this is built into the plugin)
- do not need to test the form's validity before/during the submit/click (this is also built into the plugin)

Try doing this instead...

**See DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/zuXYR/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: { 
            price: { 
                number: true 
            }, 
            size: { 
                number: true
            }
        }, 
        errorClass: 'form_fields_error',  
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            // return false;  // this will suppress errors
            error.insertAfter(element); // the default function
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // your ajax code here
            return false; // required when using ajax to prevent a page reload
        }
    });

});
```

Also, I'm not sure why you'd want your `errorPlacement` callback function to be empty.  If you want to suppress error messages, use `return false`.  Otherwise, if you want to use the default behavior, leave out the `errorPlacement` callback entirely.